# Azure Mobile Services Scheduled Delete From Table

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Can anyone help me with how I go about writing a script to delete the records from a Mobile Services table from a scheduled task? I want to clear the leader board every day and a scheduled task seems the best way to go about doing this but the documentation seems a little sketchy.

I have created the schedule but don't know how the modify the script to delete all the rows in the table.

I looked  here and  here but they haven't really shed any light.

Many thanks,

Jason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to delete the records from a table is to use the `mssql` object, and send a `DELETE` query to the database, as shown below. As usual, anytime you're sending a 'DELETE' without any filter, run it **very carefully**.

```
function MyScheduledTask() {
    var sql = 'DELETE from YourTableName'; // Run with care!!!
    mssql.query(sql, {
        success: function(results) {
            console.log('Success: ', results);
        }, error: function(err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Carlo, many thanks for the post. I also found this that includes the ability to run a stored procedure.

http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/build-your-own-sql-server-agent-for-windows-azure-sql-database-with-the-scheduler/

Regards,

Jason.