# Auto delete entry from table

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone

I'm working with windows phone apps and windows azure and I want to perform auto delete for my entry in db with condition my rating fields are less then 10 (-10), how to execute that script from server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Mobile Services to Schedule a script to do the deletes.

something similar to this: [Azure Mobile Services Scheduled Delete From Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257246/azure-mobile-services-scheduled-delete-from-table)